# Hyperscale to general purpose

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, database-administration

We have a azure hyperscale sql db. We want to restore it to general purpose.

Is anybody know to restore azure hyperscale sql database to general purpose database ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

No. The storage format for Hyperscale databases is different from any released version of SQL Server, and you don’t control backups or have access to them. To take your data out of a Hyperscale database, you can extract data using any data movement technologies, i.e. Azure Data Factory, Azure Databricks, SSIS, etc. Source: Microsoft Docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/service-tier-hyperscale-frequently-asked-questions-faq#business-continuity-and-disaster-recovery-questions?wt.mc_id=MVP).

You can also try to create a bacpac and export it to an Azure storage account, and from there import it to the other vCore tiers as explained [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/222790/copy-sql-azure-hyperscale).

Comment: Hi, Azure SQL PM here: I'd love to understand why you need to do that. Feel free to reach out to me directly to give more details if you can. Now, aside to what Alberto already correctly mentioned, I can also suggest a more friendly tool like Smart Bulk Copy: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/smartbulkcopy

Comment: Can i know which is the fastest or simpler way to copy hyperscale db to other vcore tiers ?

Comment: Export as bacpac is the easiest all data movement technologies I mentioned are time consuming

Answer (score 0):

Very recent update to this answer, you can actually do this now, but only within 45 days of going to hyperscale for some reason, so you're likely screwed:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/manage-hyperscale-database?tabs=azure-portal

Answer (score -1):

Can't you use [ALTER DATABASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current&tabs=sqlpool)? Something like the following:

```
ALTER DATABASE [db1] MODIFY (EDITION = 'GeneralPurpose');
```

Note, that you may need to specify the `MAXSIZE`, too in order to match the valid for the particular edition. For example:

```
ALTER DATABASE [db1] MODIFY (EDITION = 'Standard', MAXSIZE = 250 GB, SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = 'S0');
```

Comment: No. Actually, we want to restore the hyperscale database to non-hyperscale db.

Comment: As of today, you cannot move from an Hyperscale tier to another one, due to the completely different storage architecture

Comment: Do you have official link confirming that? I can use it to ask for edit of the documentation.